# Is platonism regarding arithmetic consistent with the multiverse view in set theory?

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy, peano-arithmetic, multiverse-of-sets

A "truth" platonist for arithmetic believes, given a statement in the language of arithmetic, that the problem whether the statement is true has a definite answer.

Prof. Hamkins has argued for a multiverse view of set theory. Since different models of ZFC can have a different arithmetic (that is, model of the natural numbers), I wonder whether platonism regarding arithmetic is consistent with the multiverse view.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question, but this is not the right forum.

Comment: @Nik: Thanks for your comment. Do you have any advice on how to rewrite the question?

Comment: Well, it's a philosophy question. This is a website for research mathematics. Maybe try the FOM discussion list?

Comment: I think, questions on philosophy of mathematics may be interesting for many working mathematicians, thus I am against closing this question.

Comment: Well, I hesitate to engage in a question that I think the community would disapprove of, but if it is going to stay open I would like to say that I defend exactly this point of view (truth platonism for arithmetic plus multiverse view of set theory) in the final chapter of [my book on forcing](http://www.amazon.com/Forcing-Mathematicians-Nik-Weaver/dp/9814566004).

Comment: @NikWeaver I'd suggest that you post a fuller answer all about it. I for one would appreciate reading it.

Comment: It seems to me that one straightforward answer is that, according to a theorem of Gitman and Hamkins, one of the axioms consistent with the "multiverse view" is that every model of set theory is ill-founded with respect to some other model. If this axiom holds, then the concept of a unique "standard" model of arithmetic becomes very doubtful. See "A natural model of the multiverse axioms", https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1285765800

Comment: @CarlMummert: so an axiom consistent with the multiverse view (MV) refutes arithmetic platonism (AP) ... are you suggesting that this implies MV and AP are inconsistent? What is the "straightforward answer" here?

Comment: @Nik Weaver: yes, I don't think the multiverse view is especially helpful for the position (which is very sympathetic) that $\omega$ has some real meaning but $2^\omega$ does not. Let's call that position $P$. The paper by Gitman and Hamkins has a list of multiverse axioms, including that the $\omega$ of any model is ill-founded in some other model.  I don't see an obvious justification why one would accept all the other multiverse axioms of that paper, but not accept that particular multiverse axiom. It seems that position $P$ in the multiverse view would require such a justification.

Comment: I noticed this because I had originally hoped that the multiverse perspective would support position $P$, but I just don't see it after looking at the paper.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Oh, I see what you mean. I suppose it depends on what you mean by "the multiverse view of set theory" --- I don't think it's unreasonable to broadly construe "there is a hierarchy of models of ZFC in which truth values of questions like CH do not stabilize, but no canonical universal model" as a multiverse view. However, I take your point.

Answer (score 21):

The view you are suggesting is something close to what is held by
Solomon Feferman, who holds that the objects and truths of
arithmetic have a definite nature that is not shared when one
moves up to higher-order objects, such as the collection of all
sets of natural numbers. Feferman has long been known for the view that the continuum hypothesis is inherently vague, in a way that arithmetic is not, and this seems to be basically what you are talking about. See for example his article

- Solomon Feferman, [Is the continuum hypothesis a definite mathematical problem?](http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Feferman_IsCHdefinite.pdf) Exploring the Frontiers of Incompleteness (EFI) Project, Harvard 2011-2012.

There are several other papers for the EFI project exploring similar issues.

One interesting aspect of the view is the idea of using classical logic in the lower more-definite realm, and intuitionistic logic in the higher realm, where assertions such as the continuum hypothesis may have a less definite meaning. Nik Weaver has pointed out in the comments below that he had first proposed this dichotomizing idea in his 2005 article:

- Nik Weaver, [Predicativity beyond $\Gamma_0$](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509244), 2005.

Finally, let me criticize your use of the term 
*Platonism* to imply a kind of singularist view of mathematical existence, whereas I have argued that it should instead imply only a kind of realism or definite existence. With this idea, the multiverse view itself is a kind of Platonism, where one gives up on the uniqueness of the existence of
mathematical objects, but not on their objective existence. For example, on the
multiverse view in set theory, there are many different concepts
of set, each giving rise to its own set-theoretic universe, which are just as real as the set theory claimed by the universists.

Comment: Joel, philosophers of mathematics sometimes distinguish between "objects platonism" (mathematical objects exist in some meaningful sense) and "truth platonism" (all the sentences of some well-defined theory have definite truth values). [See here for instance.](https://books.google.com/books?id=3cruAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22objects+platonism%22+%22truth+platonism%22&source=bl&ots=qZ2Qjky6TX&sig=IIs0WAJcSmhcA-HaRUkhtHfhVN0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf95Lltb7KAhVJyWMKHQLOB-sQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22objects%20platonism%22%20%22truth%20platonism%22&f=false)

Comment: Yes, thanks, Nik, I am aware of those other usages, and my objection is also aimed at them. My view is that the term Platonism should have something to do with real or objective existence of some kind (in the Platonic realm), that is, with realism, rather than with the singularist versus pluralist issue.  If for example we have two (or more) kinds of set-theoretic truth, they might both have an objective existence, and so it should be considered Platonist, but it wouldn't be using the terminology you cite.  And I find that unfortunate.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's quite fair to attribute the idea about dichotomizing between classical and intuitionistic logic in this way to Feferman ("he argues that"). I first proposed this in [a paper from 2005](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509244.pdf), which, not to put too fine a point on it, I know that Feferman read in detail. He switched to this position several years later.

Comment: (I should say that many others had had similar ideas earlier, but I think the specific connection to predicativism was first made by me.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that you were the source of that idea. I had thought that Feferman held this few for many years. His arguments on CH being inherently vague go back at least to the 1990s, but I'm not sure what the first source is.

Comment: Thank you for that! Yes, his arguments about CH go way back --- I think he was already suggesting this (maybe a little more obliquely) in the 1960s. Of course Weyl had said already something similar in 1918 in *Das Kontinuum* ...

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the discussion in the comments.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but are *you* an "arithmetic truth platonist"? In particular, do you believe that $\mathrm{Con}(ZFC+MC)$ has a definite truth value?

Comment: @cody No, I am not an arithmetic truth singularist, and I believe or at least worry that our concept of the finite might be less absolute and robust than is often proclaimed.  You can see a brief essay I wrote on the topic at:  http://jdh.hamkins.org/question-for-the-math-oracle/. Also, I address the issue in my multiverse paper.

Answer (score 12):

I'm still uncertain of its appropriateness here, but since Joel asked, here is a quote from [my book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814566004) that discusses this issue:

> The two kinds of independence … in geometry
>   and number theory offer us strikingly different paradigms. In
>   both cases there is broad agreement about the correct interpretation of
>   the independence results. For instance, no one nowadays would consider it
>   meaningful to ask whether the parallel postulate is "really true" in some
>   universal sense; it simply holds in some two-dimensional
>   geometries and fails in others.
>
> In contrast, although the arithmetical expression of the consistency of $PA$
>   is independent of $PA$, it is still widely regarded as true.
>   To take a more extreme example, consider the formal system
>   $MC$ = $ZFC$ + "measurable cardinals exist". Few would
>   suggest that the sentence ${\rm Con}(MC)$ which arithmetically expresses
>   that $MC$ is a consistent system might lack a well-defined truth value. Yet
>   ${\rm Con}(MC)$ is presumably independent of $PA$, indeed, presumably
>   even independent of $ZFC$.
>
> … Should we suppose
>   that the continuum hypothesis, for example, has a definite truth value in
>   a well-defined canonical model? Or is there a range of models in which the
>   truth value of the continuum hypothesis varies, none of which has any
>   special ontological priority?
>
> Forcing tends to push us in the latter direction. It creates the impression
>   that there is a range of equally valid models of $ZFC$, and that one can always
>   pass to a larger model in which the value of $2^{\aleph_0}$ changes … In an influential series of recent papers, Hamkins has vigorously argued for the
>   position that there is no canonical model of $ZFC$, a position that he calls "the multiverse view".
>
> … A picture emerges [from discussion omitted here] of a mathematical universe which is composed
>   of countable structures that have absolute properties and which includes
>   a range of countable models of $ZFC$ in which the truth values of questions
>   like the continuum hypothesis can vary. Thus, with regard to
>   independence phenomena, if we take "set theory" to be the theory of
>   surveyable collections then it has an absolute meaning and behaves like
>   number theory, but questions like the continuum hypothesis cannot even be
>   posed; if we take it to be the theory of individuals in some model
>   of $ZFC$ then it has a variable meaning and behaves like geometry.